# How to move buttons to the middle of the 1st text column?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to move facebook and twitter buttons and make them more visible on my temporary site:

[gaberivers.com](http://gaberivers.com/)

Now they are below the footer and no one can see them. I'd like to move it next to the 1st text column. Outside of that text box...that way people would see it much better.

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZWq8g/

Comment: what does your page's html look like? how are we supposed to help?

Comment: @Onheiron ok, posting it, one sec...I'll add it to the main message.

Comment: What do you mean by "next to the 1st text column?"  Left, or right?  In an existing column, or a new one?  What have you tried?

Comment: @HyperAnthony left....next to the 1st column. Outside if it...more or less at middle height.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/enhzflep/ZWq8g/8/ (added extra column, made 900px widths 964px, made new first column width 64px) Moved images into new column.

Comment: @enhzflep no, I'd like it to be outside of the actual box. On jsfiddle it is not visible, but there is space on the left and right of the 900px main body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so if I understand correctly, you're trying to move your Facebook and Twitter images to the left of your columns.  So lets make a new column, called `columnSocial` and in the CSS:

```
#columnSocial {
line-height:120px;
background-color:#394046;/*background: url(black.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;*/
width:64px;
height:250px;
float:left;
position:relative;}
```

I copied most of that from your existing columns -- be sure to edit one of the other columns width down to accommodate (your column container only allows 900px, so you need to shave off 36px somewhere else) this new column.  The `line-height` attribute is useful to get some vertical spacing, since we can't use `vertical-align` on div elements.

In your HTML, you will need to add:

```
<div id="columnSocial">
     ...
</div>
```

After your container begins and before column1 begins.  Feel free to toggle any of the numbers as you like, but that should get something similar to what you were asking for.

As a general design note, having good structure (like a container for your columns) takes a lot of the work out of changes like this -- it ended up being trivial to move the images, since all we had to do was make a new column.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to be a very very good idea. I actually want to add it on top of the 900 px. So I  simply created all the things you have posted and deleted the background color of the columnsocial in the css because I want it to melt into the background image. Now I am faced with the problem that the 3 main columns were stationary when I minimized the window but now with the social buttons there....it gets all messy when I minimize the window. I hope I can work it out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is what I managed to do: http://gaberivers.com/

But it stays aligned to the left border of the page. I'd like it to be  next to the 1st paragraph...but a few pixels outside of it. As stationary social buttons. Is there a way to make that happen?

Comment: @Elysium Should just be able to right align content in the associated div.

Comment: I was kinda thinking....that one issue here is that the social buttons are related to the movement of the whole layout. I am saying that when I drag and minimize the window, the buttons move with the window. I'd like to make them stationary and next to the main column of the website. So that they would never move when I minimize the window. I was kinda thinking of making a table (container or whatever) and move them there...but I am even newbie to that one. I really dont know what to do with it.

Comment: I have just made a column next to the main column...without background color and pasted the icons there. Thanks for the idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:-
your footer should be like

```
<div id="footer" style="text-align: center;">
<p>&copy; 2012 Angloesfera. Todos los derechos reservados.</p>
<div id="snetworks">
        <a class="show" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Academ%C3%ADa-AngloEsfera/190496871000029"> <!--a http-vel kell a link...vagy          kulonben az en oldalamon belul fogja keresni a linket-->
        <img width="36" height="36" rel="" title="" alt="facebook" src="images/facebook.png"></a>

        <a class="show" href="https://twitter.com/GoE_Shop">
        <img width="36" height="36" rel="" title="" alt="facebook" src="images/twitter.png"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

and css for #snetworks

```
#snetworks {
    left: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
}
```